# Generic type parameter and Nullable method overload

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, nullable

Hi 
I have this code using generic and nullable:

```
// The first one is for class
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
          Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
    where TResult : class
    where TInput : class

// The second one is for struct (Nullable)
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this Nullable<TInput> o, 
          Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
    where TResult : class
    where TInput : struct
```

Please note the TInput constraint, one is class, the other one is struct. Then I use them in:

```
string s;
int? i;

// ...

s.With(o => "");
i.With(o => ""); // Ambiguos method
```

It cause an Ambiguos error. But I also have the another pair:

```
public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o,
          Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
    where TInput : class

public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>(this Nullable<TInput> o,
          Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
    where TInput : struct
```

This one compiles successfully

```
string s;
int? i;

// ...

s.Return(o => 1, 0);
i.Return(o => i + 1, 0);
```

I got no clues why this happen. The first one seems Ok, but compiles error. The second one ('Return') should be error if the first one is, but compiles successfully. Did I miss something?

Comment: Just as a style comment, I'd avoid using the same name for a lambda parameter as for a variable already in scope.

Comment: ah right, that actually cause a compile error. I just paste and edit the code hastily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constraints within the generic method are not considered while *choosing* an overload - they're checked *after* the overload has been chosen.

Constraints within the types of the parameters *are* checked as part of choosing an overload. It's a bit confusing, but it makes sense eventually.

I have a [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints) on this which may help to understand it further.

Additionally note that your second example has the additional argument which contributes to type inference, which is what makes the difference between the two. `TResult` is inferred to be `int`, which prevents the first overload from being valid - there's no conversion from `(int? x) => x + 1` to `Func<int?, int>` whereas there *is* a conversion from `(int x) => x + 1` to `Func<int, int>`.

Comment: I'm pretty consufed right now, and I'm trying to understand your last paragraph. Both of the Func<> delegates don't use nullable (int?) at all. Only the first parameters are.

Comment: @Hendry: The first overload in each case will treat `TInput = int?` because you're calling it on an `int?`. The `evaluator` parameter type would therefore be `Func<int?, TResult>`.

Comment: oh i see, that's why the overload resolution, based on the lambda function, fail on the first 'Return' and flows to the second one. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please consider updating the link.